# out of swap - memory leak or t1.micro too small for what i need

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, amazon-ec2

Had an issue today with my ec2 instance.  Ran out of SWAP, so mysql shut down.  When I looked at memory available, SWAP was indeed 0.

Then, I tried top, sorting by swap and saw that my 12 node instances were the top hitters.  See attached.
[image]

Here are my theories of what's happening:

1) There is a memory leak with node (my code, rather than node itself).  However, I don't get the sense that the VIRT and RES is big enough to assume this.  Also, with the latest versions of node, there is garbage collection so most of leaked memory should be collected.

2) My EC2 is a t1.micro instance.  This instance is too small to handle 12 instances of node.

Any thoughts on this?

Anything I can do to check or verify exactly what the issue is and what I should do about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EC2 micro instances don't have any swap space by default. If you are short on memory it's a good idea to add some swap. You can add a 1 GB swap to your instance with these commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

To enable it by default after reboot, add this line to /etc/fstab:

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and run your code through a profiler. This will give you a good idea if there is in fact a memory leak or at least what it is so heavy in it.